# Make the player slide down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make it so when my player is in touching the wall he is sliding down to the ground but right now if I press to move forwards, towards the wall my player is sliding just for a very short time and then stops.
If I don't press any button is working correctly but I have to make it slide even when the key's are pressed.

**This is the code for wall sliding and movement:**

```
 private void MyInput()

{
    horizontalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    verticalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
}

private void MovePlayer()
{
    moveDirection = orientation.forward * verticalInput + orientation.right * horizontalInput;

    rb.AddForce(moveDirection.normalized * moveSpeed * 10f, ForceMode.Force);
}

private void SpeedControl()
{
    Vector3 flatVel = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, 0f, rb.velocity.z);

    //limit vel
    if(flatVel.magnitude > moveSpeed)
    {
        Vector3 limitedVel = flatVel.normalized * moveSpeed;
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(limitedVel.x, rb.velocity.y, limitedVel.z);
    }


}

private void checkForWall()
{
    if (Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, 0.7f, LayerMask.GetMask("Wall")))
    {
        touchWall = true;
    }
    else
    {
        touchWall = false;

    }
}

private void WallSlide()
{
    if(touchWall && !grounded)
    {
        isWallSliding = true;
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, Mathf.Clamp(rb.velocity.y, -wallSlidingSpeed, float.MaxValue));
    }
    else
    {
        isWallSliding = false;
    }
}
```

And here is a photo of how my player get stuck:

[image]